# Exclude directories when using hg purge

Tags: powershell, version-control, mercurial, teamcity, purge

I am trying to perform an `hg purge` in my repository but I need to exclude some directories (e.g. `node_modules`, and something else) from that purge.

Basically, I want to keep (not-delete) these directories, in order to avoid downloading them again everytime.

This is about my build process, it runs `hg purge` before starting a new build process and consequently removes everything that is ignored (listed in `.hgignore`). I don't want this to happen for directories as `node_modules` and some other else.

Is there any way to tell Mercurial not to make purge on some directories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-X`/`--exclude` command line switch (can be specified more than once):

```
hg purge -X 'glob:node_modules/**.js'
```

The above pattern ignores all Javascript files in the `node_modules` directory, including those in subdirectories. Use `/**` to match everything under a directory:

```
hg purge -X 'glob:node_modules/**'
```

See the [*File names and pattern matching* chapter](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/file-names-and-pattern-matching.html) in the Mercurial guide; the patterns described there can all be used here.

When testing your patterns, make sure you use the `--print` command-line option to `hg purge`, it'll then only *print* what files will be removed. This helps when iterating your patterns, you don't have to keep re-instating your files between tries.